# Creation of an object based on the user's choice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hello i have some UML diagram here:
[image]

So the issue is that I would like to create an employee object depending on user choice:
[image]

But i dont know how to do it in a controller. Right now controller looks like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Imie,Nazwisko,Pesel,Data_zatrudnienia,Data_zwolnienia,Pensja,Wyksztalcenie,Nazwa_uzytkownika,Uprawnienia")] Pracownik pracownik)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Pracownik.Add(pracownik);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


        return View(pracownik);
    }
```

And the code that you see above creates two types of workers. And I want to just create one depending on the user's choice.

In view I create html object depending on the value of dropdown list. Like this:

```
  <script>
function handleChange() {

    var strg = "";
    var text1 = '<div class="form-group"> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pracownik_biurowy.Nazwa_uzytkownika, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" }) <div class="col-md-10">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pracownik_biurowy.Nazwa_uzytkownika, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pracownik_biurowy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) </div> </div>';
    var text2 = ' <div class="form-group">  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Przewodnik.Uprawnienia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" }) <div class="col-md-10"> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Przewodnik.Uprawnienia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</div></div>';

                $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                    strg = strg + this.value;
                });

                if (strg == "biurowy") {
                    $('#typPracownik').html(text1);


                }

                if (strg == "przewodnik") {

                    $('#typPracownik').html(text2);


                }


            }

            $('#pracownicy').change(handleChange);


        </script>
```

Osoba:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Osoba
{
    public int Id_osoby { get; set; }
    public string Imie { get; set; }
    public string Nazwisko { get; set; }
    public string Pesel { get; set; }

    public virtual Klient Klient { get; set; }
    public virtual Pracownik Pracownik { get; set; }
}
```

}

Pracownik :

```
 public partial class Pracownik
{
    public int Id_osoby { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Data_zatrudnienia { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Data_zwolnienia { get; set; }
    public double Pensja { get; set; }
    public string Wyksztalcenie { get; set; }

    public virtual Osoba Osoba { get; set; }
    public virtual Pracownik_biurowy Pracownik_biurowy { get; set; }
    public virtual Przewodnik Przewodnik { get; set; }
}
```

Pracownik biurowy:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Pracownik_biurowy
{
    public int Id_osoby { get; set; }

    public string Nazwa_uzytkownika { get; set; }

    public virtual Pracownik Pracownik { get; set; }
}
```

Przewodnik:

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Przewodnik
{
    public Przewodnik()
    {
        this.Wycieczka_fakultatywna = new HashSet<Wycieczka_fakultatywna>();
    }

    public int Id_osoby { get; set; }

    public string Uprawnienia { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Id_regionu { get; set; }

    public virtual Pracownik Pracownik { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Wycieczka_fakultatywna> Wycieczka_fakultatywna { get; set; }
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'd stop posting your Model object. Post, instead, a View Model object where you include employee type and create right instance (based on that) in your controller method.

Comment: oh sorry, now edited.

Comment: @DanielDziubecki, What Adriano means is to use a view model that contains all the properties you edit. Post back that view model and based on the selected employee type, initialize a new instance of the relevant type and save it.